# Click and Type Applecript code not working

Tags: applescript, automator

I am making a service in Automator that runs the following AppleScript code:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "System Events"
        click at {393, 77}
        delay 0.1
        keystroke "Hello"
        delay 0.1
        keystroke return
    end tell
    return input

end run
```

If you couldn't tell, I'm trying to click on something and type "Hello" there. However, when I run this, all that happens is I hear the "plunk" sound when you do something invalid, twice. Why isn't this code working?

The log does say "Run AppleScript completed" and then "Workflow completed."

I have it set to run with no input on any application.

I tried increasing the delays, but that didn't help.

Let me know if there's any more details I can provide.

Comment: It doesn't work because the `click at` function doesn't actually simulate a system mouse click, it appears more to trigger an `AXPress` action associated with the object underneath the cursor at the time.  Therefore, it will appear to click menu items and buttons, as those objects have this action programmed into them; but it would, for example, put focus onto a text field.  Your code is fine - but it's just expecting `click at` to do something it cannot do.

Comment: Anyway, keystroking text entry is really a last resort kind of technique - what specific app are you using, or what website and text field are you targeting ?  There's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @CJK I'm trying to type a chat message into chat systems like Skype. I was hoping I could use it for more than one app though, hence why I did the keystroke method.

Comment: @CJK So there's no way to simulate an actual mouse click?

Comment: No, there is no way to simulate a "physical" mouse click with ordinary AppleScript; and, as far as I know, even AS-ObjC can't do it (although it used to be able to, and may be able to again in the future).  You would have to use a plug in/scripting addition as suggested in the answer below.

Comment: And having said there's probably a better way to do it, if you're using the new _Skype_ (v8+), your method is, sadly, the only way.  The new version of _Skype_ is made with ElectronJS: it's basically just a web app made of HTML and CSS, so doesn't provide the accessibility hooks  for scripting that normal macOS apps do.  The old _Skype_ (and other macOS apps) would have allowed AppleScript to change the contents of the message field programmatically, then trigger the send button, and the window wouldn't even need to be in focus.  Sorry to get your hopes up.  It's a real pain.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest downloading [AppleScript toolbox scripting addition.](https://astoolbox.wordpress.com/)  Once installed in the proper locations, in Script Editor.app, , you will be able to use commands from the key and mouse suite from the AppleScript toolbox dictionary to…get, set, and click at mouse locations (coordinates)

Here is some sample code using commands from the AppleScript toolbox dictionary

---

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
set mousePointLocation1 to {745, 110} -- The Collapsed Menu
set mousePointLocation2 to {780, 340} -- TV Link In The Menu
set mousePointLocation3 to {885, 180} -- Apple TV 4K Icon

delay 1 -- For Demonstration Purposes
activate application "Safari"
delay 1 -- For Demonstration Purposes

AST click at mousePointLocation1 ¬
    number of clicks 1

delay 1 -- For Demonstration Purposes

AST click at mousePointLocation2 ¬
    number of clicks 1

delay 1 -- For Demonstration Purposes

AST click at mousePointLocation3 ¬
    number of clicks 1
```

[image]

[image]

---

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
-- For Demonstration Purposes
-- Gives Me Time To Put The Mouse Where I Want
delay 3

-- Gets Coordinates Of The Current Mouse Location
set currentMouseLocation to AST mouse point location

-- Mouse Click At Defined Location
AST click at currentMouseLocation ¬
    number of clicks 2 -- How Many Clicks
```

[image]

---

**EXAMPLE 3**

```
set mousePointLocation to {20.0, 20.0}

delay 1 -- For Demonstration Purposes

AST set mouse point location mousePointLocation ¬
    without holding mouse down

delay 1 -- For Demonstration Purposes

AST click at mousePointLocation ¬
    number of clicks 1
```

[image]

Comment: I will try this, but do you know why my initial code didn't work?

Comment: Without knowing all the information such as which application you're trying to click in, etc... There's no way to isolate where the error Is being triggered